# Declaring data type of a variable using a condition in c

Tags: c, variables, conditional-statements, custom-data-type

I want to declare data type of a variable depending on a condition in C. Is it possible?

I have written a program to implement stack using integer array,
and I want the same code to implement stack of characters which is nothing but replacing some "int"s by "char"s, So how to do that??

I trid something like,

```
if(x == 1)
#define DATATYPE int
else
#define DATATYPE char
```

and many other things too but nothing worked.

Comment: You can do this kind of thing elegantly in C++ with templates, but for C your only option really is ugly hacks using preprocessor macros. Check out C11's `_Generic` capability though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision).

Comment: You _tried_ that? You should know that the preprocessor acts performing text substitution before the compiler kicks in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code could work with `#if x==1` ... `#endif` if `x` is a *preprocessor* symbol, e.g. if you compile with `-Dx=1` command-line [option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to `gcc` ; please understand that the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) is the first phase of a C compiler, which in fact sees *preprocessed* code (use e.g. `gcc -C -E source.c > source.i` to get into `source.i` the preprocessed form of `source.c`)

In general, you could implement such generic containers using huge preprocessor macros. See e.g. [sglib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sglib/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c). Or you could generate your C code with some specialized source code generator (perhaps using another preprocessor like [m4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29) or [gpp](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP), or crafting your own generator in some scripting language).

Alternatively, use a lot of `void*` pointers, and pass the size of data to your routines, like [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) does. See e.g. [Glib containers](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-data-types.html)

You might be interested in learning [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) or [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/index.en.html) (or even Common Lisp). They offer a standard library with several generic [containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_%28abstract_data_type%29) (in C++ with [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29) in the library, in Ocaml with [functors](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/functors.html) in it); read also about [generic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming)

Comment: Thanks..I think the "sglib" will be useful..At the same time, playing with void* pointers is a bit challenging and worth considering..:)..Thanks for other references you have shared

Comment: What does "if you compile with -Dx=1" actually mean..I didnt get that

Comment: Added a link. It is a command-line flag to `gcc`  and every other command line compiler I know (`clang`, `tcc`, `nwcc` ...)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a design flaw. You should really ask yourself why you want to threat C as a dynamic language like Python. C is a statically language typed, so types are fixed.

Comment: It might not be a *design flaw* but a *design decision*

Answer (score 1):

Use this solution which encourage you to redesign by creating a struct for each value in the stack `tagged_t`,and then fill the data, I hope you get the idea.

```
    typedef union {
int i;
char c;
float f;
} evil;

typedef struct {
  evil value;
  int type;
} tagged_t;

enum {
  TYPE_INT, TYPE_CHAR, TYPE_FLOAT
};

tagged_t bar;
bar.value.c = 'a';
bar.type = TYPE_CHAR;
```

[See the answer of Yann Ramin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822795/how-i-change-a-variable-of-a-type-to-another-one-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please learn about the pre-processor. Now, on to your question.

This does not work, due to the fact that the compiler only actually sees:

```
if(x == 1)
else
```

The `#` indicates that the instruction will be executed by the pre-processor. The pre-processor is really a glorified find-and-replace when we talk about the `#define` command. eg:

```
#define PI_5_DIGITS 3.14159f
```

The pre-processor will find all occurrences of the tag `PI_5_DIGITS` and replace it with `3.14159`.

Should you want to use this, make `x` a pre-processor symbol, by adding the switch e.g. `-Dx=1.`

Your code would then need to be changed to:

```
#ifdef x
   #define DATATYPE int
#else
  #define DATATYPE char
#endif
```

Suggested reading:

http://www.phanderson.com/C/preprocess.html
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp

Comment: Wrong fix. The GCC URL does not contain `www`

Comment: Fixed my fail...moral: always check your links.

Comment: Thank you for the links you shared..they are really helpful..thanks.